# Different framework needed for iOS app to consume web service

Tags: ios, json, web-services

I would like to ask what are the framework/library that I need in the app side to consume web service via REST.

Currently I have SBJson to parse JSON and ASIHTTPRequest framework. Is ASIHTTPRequest the REST Protocol? Or do I have to add in another REST lib on top of ASIHTTPRequest.

Another problem is that ASIHTTPRequest framework is no longer being maintained since last year. So will it still work for the current iOS 5 with ARC?

Besides the SBJson and ASIHTTPRequest, are there anymore framework/library that I've miss out in order to consume a web service?

Will be glad if anyone can guide my in the right direction

EDIT: I found another framework RESTkit. Does this framework replace the ASIHTTPRequest framework or do they work together hand in hand? First time doing webservice and consuming it from iOS side. So I may ask alot of silly question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REST is not a protocol, it is an architecture.  It just describes a certain style of web service design.  You don't need any special framework to communicate with a RESTful service.  SBJson and ASIHHTPRequest should be more than sufficient for your needs.

As for ASIHTTPRequest working with ARC, all you have to do is set the -fno-objc-arc compiler flag on each of the source files.  See this question for more information:

[How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

You could also build ASIHTTPRequest as a static library (without ARC) and link against it in your app.

Comment: I found another framework RESTkit. Does this framework replace the ASIHTTPRequest framework or do they work together hand in hand?

Comment: That would replace ASIHTTPRequest, and I'm pretty sure it also includes SBJson and does the parsing behind the scenes so you wouldn't need to worry about that either.

Comment: thank you very much! Make me have a much clearer understanding of what I need to know to get started.